# Why does this program only typecheck if I remove either usage of a function

Tags: haskell, type-inference, typeclass

This program wont type check:

```
$ runghc a.hs

a.hs:12:25:
    Couldn't match expected type `Word32' with actual type `Integer'
    In the second argument of `div', namely `ix'
    In the expression: len "ABCDEF" `div` ix
    In an equation for `iy': iy = len "ABCDEF" `div` ix
```

but if I remove `wy` or `iy`, it does. Why?

```
import Data.Word
import Data.List

len = genericLength

wx :: Word32
wx = 3
wy = len "ABCDEF" `div` wx

ix :: Integer
ix = 3
iy = len "ABCDEF" `div` ix

main = print 1
```

Comment: The question should probably be *"Why does haskell deduce `[a] -> Word32` instead of `Num i => [a] -> i`"*. I have no idea why it would, but apparently it does...

Answer (score 4):

Its probably because of `MonomorphismRestriction`. If you dont give an explicit type to `len` haskell will always interpret a monomorphic type for that. So in this case the first time it sees `len` it interprets its type to `[a] -> Word32`. Now the second time `len` is used it finds the expected type to be `[a] -> Integer` and returns a type error. Giving `len` an explicit type fixes that.

```
len :: Integral i => [a] -> i
len = genericLength
```

or add `NoMonomorphismRestriction` language extension which removes this restriction.

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}
```

Comment: A third alternative would be to make the argument to `len` explicit – i.e. write the definition as `len xs = genericLength xs`.

Comment: @kqr How type inference differs in the two cases?

Comment: With the arguments explicit, GHC doesn't perform the monomorphism restriction. You can try it for yourself by creating an alias for any polymorphic function, like `fromIntegral`. I haven't cared enough to find out why it's like that, but that's the way it is.